# Cannot display array of items on page useEffect reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I cannot display my array of items
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDm0k.png)

Here is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RM2T.png)

Here is my ProductItem.js code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyPk1.png)

I want the elements of array to display on my webpage. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198).